# Docker-compose Django Supervisord Configuration

Tags: python, django, docker, supervisord

I would like to run some programs when my django application running. That's why I choose supervisord. I configured my docker-compose and Dockerfile like :

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# some of project settings here
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
ADD supervisor-worker.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

docker-compose:

```
  api:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: project
    volumes:
      - .:/project
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" 
    network_mode: "host"
```

supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf

[supervisorctl]

[inet_http_server]
port=*:9001
username=root
password=root
```

So my problem is when I up the docker-compose project and other dependencies (postgresql, redis) works fine but supervisord didn't work. When I run "supervisord" command inside container it's working. But in startup, It don't work.

Comment: You’re overriding the command for the api service in your docker compose config.

Comment: ...and the application code, and disabling Docker networking.  You should be able to reduce the `docker-compose.yml` block to just `build:` and `ports:` and use Docker defaults for the rest of it.